# Hibernate Search 5.2+ programmatic configuration of facet field

Tags: lucene, annotations, hibernate-search, faceted-search

Before Hibernate Search 5.2 there was no need to explicitly use a @Facet annotation. In 5.2 it became necessary in order to use Lucene’s native faceting API.

I'm using Hibernate Search on external classes that cannot be annotated. Is there a way to define this "facet" programmatically?

For the mapping configuration, there is no issue because the SearchMapping provides a complete programmatic alternative to the @Entity, @Indexed, and @Field annotations. But within this API, and in particular in the EntityMapping class, there is no way to define that a field will be used in a facet query; there is no other alternative rather than annotating the field with @Facet.

**2018 update:** 
I've updated to Hibernate Search 5.6.4 and it is working with this kind of mappings:

```
.property("businessProcess", ElementType.METHOD)
            .field()
                .analyze(Analyze.NO)
                .store(Store.YES)
                .facet()
                    .name("businessProcess")
                    .encoding(FacetEncodingType.STRING)
```

Comment: It is a bug. I created a ticket to address it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2650 . Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: I'm using Hibernate Search 5.6.4 now, and the facet() call in the programmatic mapping, but the exception is still thrown. Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: Did you index your data prior to querying? In older versions of Hibernate Search such as 5.6, this exception is known to be caused by an index where no facet was actually indexed: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2955

Comment: It is working now after adding an explicit name for the facets with the .name("foo") calls. However, I cannot make it work on a custom Calendar bridge. Would you mind checking my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574478/hibernate-search-configure-facet-for-custom-fieldbridge/44556806#44556806

Answer (score 1):

The [workaround you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574478/hibernate-search-configure-facet-for-custom-fieldbridge/44556806#44556806) does not configure faceting in Hibernate Search at all (no @Facet annotation nor programmatic equivalent). In recent versions of Hibernate Search, this will not work, because we had to require this metadata in order to fix [other bugs](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2955).

Using custom facet formatting is very much uncharted territory, and admittedly much harder than it should be. The main reason is that facets were originally, for a reason I cannot fathom, designed to work directly on the entity property instead of the field value. Thus, facets ignore the field bridge. We're working on cleaning up the faceting support in Search 6, but this one of many works in progress and will take some time.

In the meantime, your easiest option will probably be to just use the built-in formatting.

**EDIT:** Also, for dates you might want to use numeric facet formatting, so as to perform range faceting (from the first of May to the 30th of may). In that case, the name of facets is defined at query time, so built-in formatting should not matter.

And there's actually one easy solution to customize formatting in your string-encoded facets, but I didn't mention it since you are using programmatic mapping and probably do not want to change your model: you could add read-only properties returning the exact value you want in your facet (`getYear`, `getMonth`, ...), and add fields with faceting on those properties.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the model adding the read-only properties, despite I was trying to avoid that option. 
I was not able to use the built-in formatting because I need to facet for example on the month, regardless of the year; so a range query on the date does not meet the requirement.